# Determine string occurrence in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have a stringified array:

```
JSON.stringify(arr) = [{"x":9.308,"y":6.576,"color":"yellow","restitution":0.2,"type":"static","radius":1,"shape":"square","width":0.25,"height":0.25},{"x":9.42,"y":7.488,"color":"yellow","restitution":0.2,"type":"static","radius":1,"shape":"square","width":0.25,"height":0.25}]
```

I need to find out how many times the word yellow occurs so I can do something like:

```
numYellow = 0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i] === "yellow")
  numYellow++;
}

doSomething = function() {
  If (numYellow < 100) {
    //do something
  }
  If(numYellow > 100) {
    //do something else
  } else { do yet another thing} 
  }
```

Comment: What does `.stringify()` have to do with this? If it's really stringified, it can't be iterated like you're doing.

Comment: You can do it without stringify the array. See @Ashwins answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each element of the array is an object.  Change `arr[i]` to `arr[i].color`.  This does assume that the `.color` property is the only spot where `yellow` will exist, though.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var array = [{"x":9.308,"y":6.576,"color":"yellow","restitution":0.2,"type":"static","radius":1,"shape":"square","width":0.25,"height":0.25},{"x":9.42,"y":7.488,"color":"yellow","restitution":0.2,"type":"static","radius":1,"shape":"square","width":0.25,"height":0.25}]

var numYellow = 0;

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].color === "yellow") {
        numYellow++;
    }
}
```